# AngularJS - ng-include binding

Tags: angularjs

I have a binding problem when I use ng-directive.

I read some other post but I don't succedd bind variable in my ng-include.

```
    <ng-include src="'template.html'"                 
            ng-repeat="item in bloc.items"               
            onload="data=item; highlight=forceHighlight;"></ng-include>
```

forceHighlight is a scope variable who are well initialized but when the variable change in the controller, change are not passed into the template.

Here a fiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/h24gtw51/2/

The goal is to have a template who display "text" or "zone" or "image", then if i click on the checkbox highlight i want display a border on "text"

I test to add controller in the ng-include but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually bind the variable inside the include - your parent scope is automatically binded, so you can just access it. If you change your directive to use `forceHighlight` (ignore the onload assignment), your example will work :)

[Look at this version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/h24gtw51/3/)

Comment: Sorry, the last fiddle was setted with angular 1.1.1. We felt it worked. But <p> with bar is not encapsulate by border. I update the fiddle to use angular 1.2.1. The problem is that the zone directive don't pass the correct value to the ng-include. I succes to solve the problem in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h24gtw51/5/. Really thanks for your help